# Javascript Promise return value

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am trying to make a crawler, and as the data is not showing in the page source, I can only execute the javascript with the web driver and get the response, and then do the data analysis.
The script is simplified, like this, use Promise.

```
var res = ""

function f1() {
    p = window.Promise
    a = p.resolve(5).then(function(value) {
        console.log(value)
        res = value
        return res
    })
    return a
}
console.log(f1()) // Promise object
console.log("result = ", res) // res is empty
```

My program is like this, writing with c#:

```
 public void GetParameters(string url)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
            string script = readFile(@"C:\myscript.js", Encoding.UTF8).TrimEnd(); // The script is a bit long, so I save it to a local file.
            var json = js.ExecuteScript(script);
            Console.WriteLine("Get the return value");
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            driver.Close();
        }
```

I want to get the value, and I know `then` always return Promise object, so I define a variable, and want to store the value to it. But seems that, the Promise is executed asynchronous, so the res always be empty.

OK, I'm writing a crawler, and use Selenium to get the response from the server (Selenium.webdriver can open a web browser, and then execute script), I need get the result, as it will use by another program. So, I can not just add another .then, just output the value. Maybe I can save to a local file, and then read it, but I think it is inefficient.

Anyone can help?

Comment: You're using promises incorrectly. `f1().then(res => console.log('result=', res))`. See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for more.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [`executeAsyncScript` instead](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeAsyncScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)? (this is the Java documentation but there must be something similar for C#).  `executeScript` appears to be for synchronous  JavaScript which you apparently do not have. If I understand your question correctly, you don't have control over the JavaScript? But yes, promises are asynchronous.

Comment: year, there is also a function executeAsyncScript in C#, but when I call it, an error will be thrown said that cannot get the result in 0 seconds, then I set the timeout time to 5 seconds(5 seconds is enough to get the response), but it also said that cannot get the result in 5 second ... Then I give up this way, and I find another way to get the result. I try to create an element in the page, and set the text to the return value. After that, search for the element I created. It works! Anyway, thanks for you suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to log the global `res`, the result hasn't been computed yet. When using Promises, you have to get the result asynchronously, using `.then`, like this:

```
f1().then(res => console.log("result =", res));
```

Comment: This question was obviously a duplicate. Why answer it? Comment (since the answer is so simple) and then search for duplicate to flag.

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909460/javascript-promise-return, oh, come one, I have search it before, and my problem is not same as that, because the "get the value" and "use the value" is two part, and also in two different process.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the current code you're working on with Selenium?

Answer (score 2):

Try this
You're using promises incorrectly.

`f1().then(res => console.log('result=', res)).`